# Make different MySQL queries with different buttons

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

What I want to do is have different buttons, and when each one of it is clicked, it makes a different query in a MySQL from the others. For example, button A -> query A, button B -> query B, and so on (it doesn't matter what query right now). I have no idea how to do this (i searched a lot but I didn't find something useful). If you could give me some directions, i would be very grateful. This is what I have so far:

EDITED: I know how to send data from a form and how to make MySQL queries with PHP. What I DON'T know is how to assign this different queries to different buttons (for example, a button to create a database, other one for delete, other  one for create a table, etc). I didn't add the queries because they are not important right now, I just want to do if exists a way to do (for example,a javascript function that check if the button is pressed, then make the ajax call, open a connection, make the query, return a result and close the connection).

JAVASCRIPT

```
window.addEventListener("load", process);

var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){ 
    var xmlHttp;
    try {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e){
        var XmlHttpVersions = new Array("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0",
                                        "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0",
                                        "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0",
                                        "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0",
                                        "MSXML2.XMLHTTP",
                                        "Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        for (var i=0; i<XmlHttpVersions.length && !xmlHttp; i++){
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject(XmlHttpVersions[i]);
            }
            catch (e){}
        }
    }
    if (!xmlHttp)
        alert("Error creating the XMLHttpRequest object.");
    else
        return xmlHttp;
}

function process(){
    if (xmlHttp){
        try {
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "server_script.php?", true);
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
        catch (e){
            alert("Can't connect to server:\n" + e.toString());
        }
    }
}

function handleRequestStateChange(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200){
            try {
                handleServerResponse();
            }
            catch(e){
                alert("Error reading the response: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("There was a problem retrieving the data:\n" +
            xmlHttp.statusText);
        }
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
    document.getElementById("ResponseDiv").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "root";
    $password   = "";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    if($conn -> connect_error) {
        die("Connectio failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected sucesfully";

    $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: step back and look at what you're attempting: send data from a form (even if it's via ajax) to the server and do something with the submitted data. so learn how to process a form on the server, and then the rest just flows naturally.

Comment: @MarcB I know how to send data from a form. What i want to do is create buttons, for example, to create o delete databases, tables, and other things. I know how to do all of this in php, but I don't know how to assign it to differents buttons.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make the query, first of all:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: OP is using `mysqli_` not `mysql_`

Comment: oh, and that's not my downvote, in case you may be wondering.

Comment: well. I don't know why this was downvoted. He's not making the actual queries.

Comment: you're right, but the person who downvoted you probably did that because of the difference in MySQL APIs. Questions like this, I for one would have never posted an answer; not before we know what the full picture looks like. There's nothing like the Mona Lisa ;-)

Comment: well. I am not allowed to comment. I need a 50 reputation. So the only thing I can do is post an answer.

Comment: anyway the down vote won't help this person understand.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more. Sorry, but people can be rather strange animals at times and we don't know why. All we can do is try and understand ;-) cheers

Comment: This system doesn't encourage beginners to participate. The question was downvoted as well.

Comment: Yes, i don't know why i was downvoted. Maybe i wasn't clear enough,but whoever did it, instead of downvoted me, could ask me to be more specific. Anyway, I edited the question; maybe now is more clear.

Comment: @ontheway for assingning to buttons on php you use the property of your form and trigger it with a submit. check this: <form action="yourcodepage.php" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button><br>
  <button type="submit" formaction="yourcodepage.php">Submit as admin</button>
</form> //// I took this code from here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp

Comment: @guergana yes, but that just redirect you to the php page, and I need to stay in the same html page where the buttons are, and make the call with ajax.

Comment: So your question is about AJAX? Use a different php file and ajax for each button... I'd do it with Jquery instead of plain javascript. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/   I think what you know and what you don't know is not very clear.